# How to number a tree entity object that extends parent's number?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, recursion

I have an Item entity

```
@Entity
public class Item {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Item parentItem;

  private String name;

  private String number;

  // getters & setters

}
```

I want a function that generates numbers with the following rules:

- root elements get a single number like 1. 2.
- child element extends its parent number and get a number like 1.1.  1.2
- other descendant elements also extends their parent number like 1.1.1. 1.1.2
- there is no limit on descendant levels.

Answer (score 0):

just go through (from the leave to the root) the tree and concat the numbers:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Item parentItem;

  private String name;

  private String number;

  String getHierarchy(){
    return this.parentItem != null ? 
             this.parentItem.getHierarchy() + " . " + this.number :
             this.number
  }

}
```